# Tree structure under "Documents"

Tags: folder, menu, left-navigation

I want to create different folders under "DOCUMENTS" in left side pane. To be clear, I do not want folders to appear on right side pane when I click on documents but want them to appear underneath the"DOCUMENT". How do I do this?

[image: this is what I am trying to achieve].

Please assist.

Comment: Simply understand you want tree view structure for your document library. Is it right?

Comment: sounds like a custom quick launch tree structure. When you click on the folder, it will appear in the document library view to the right side of the screen. The tree view is the closest you are going to get without custom development.

Comment: I added an image of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Guys, I really need help with this one.